# Existence of a prime ideal containing all but one minimal prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Does there exist a prime ideal containing all but one minimal prime ideal in an unital commutative Noetherian ring $A$, for any given minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$?

I encountered this statement while trying to prove the finiteness of the set of minimal prime ideals of an unital commutative Noetherian ring.

Any help is appreciated.

Yours gratefully,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $k$ be a field and consider $R=k\times k \times k$. The prime ideals of $R$ are $k\times k \times 0$, $k\times 0\times k$, and $0\times k\times k$, so no prime ideal contains all but one minimal prime.

Verifying the claim that a noetherian ring has finitely many minimal primes can be done in lots of different ways depending on your preferences. I'd suggest a quick search of MSE or the web to find proofs that you like - for instance, as a geometer I like something along the lines of [00FR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FR), but those who are more commutative algebra minded may prefer a different approach.